# Use Dijkstra's to find a Minimum Spanning Tree?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory, dijkstra, minimum-spanning-tree

[Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is typically used to find the shortest distance between two nodes in a graph. Can it be used to find a minimum [spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)? If so, how?

Edit: This isn't homework, but I am trying to understand a question on an old practice exam.

Comment: You use Greedy to find MST. For Shortest path, you use Principle of optimality (Optimal substructure), Dynamic programming. In DP, you find the graph Bottom up and each stage is optimal. For greedy, you just pick a greedy criteria and you find the MST. If you understand Greedy and DP, you can really feel the difference. MST shouldnt contain Cycle. Shortest Path can contain cycle. Try to understand the underlying theory of how to find them and you ll understand the difference better. Shortest Path is NP complete where MST is not. If you could use MST to solve Shortest path. then P=NP.

Comment: This comment is incorrect as Shortest path is certainly not NP complete. Proof is that Dijkstra's algorithm is Polynomial. Instead of using a strict Dijkstra algorithm with a priority queue based on distance to one node, use a priority queue based on the edges weight. At each step add the frontier edge that has the smallest weight and doesn't create a cycle.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Strictly, the answer is no. Dijkstra's algorithm finds the shortest path between 2 vertices on a graph. However, a very small change to the algorithm produces another algorithm which does efficiently produce an MST.

[The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600) is the best book I've found to answer questions like this one.

Answer (score 70):

The answer is no.  To see why, let's first articulate the question like so:

#### Q: For a connected, undirected, weighted graph `G = (V, E, w)` with only nonnegative edge weights, does the predecessor subgraph produced by Dijkstra's Algorithm form a minimum spanning tree of G?

(Note that undirected graphs are a special class of directed graphs, so it is perfectly ok to use Dijkstra's Algorithm on undirected graphs.  Furthermore, MST's are defined only for connected, undirected graphs, and are trivial if the graph is not weighted, so we must restrict our inquiry to these graphs.)

A: **Dijkstra's Algorithm** at every step greedily selects the next edge that is closest to some **source vertex s**.  It does this until s is connected to every other vertex in the graph.  Clearly, the predecessor subgraph that is produced is a spanning tree of `G`, but is the sum of edge weights minimized?

**Prim's Algorithm**, which is known to produce a minimum spanning tree, is highly similar to Dijkstra's Algorithm, but at each stage it greedily selects the next edge that is closest to **any vertex currently in the working MST at that stage**.  Let's use this observation to produce a counterexample.

Counterexample:  Consider the undirected graph `G = (V, E, w)` where

`V = { a, b, c, d }`

`E = { (a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,d), (c,d) }`

`w = {
    ( (a,b) , 5 )
    ( (a,c) , 5 )
    ( (a,d) , 5 )
    ( (b,d) , 1 )
    ( (c,d) , 1 ) 
}`

Take `a` as the source vertex.

[image: Picture of the Graph G]

Dijkstra's Algorithm takes edges `{ (a,b), (a,c), (a,d) }`.
Thus, the total weight of this spanning tree is **5 + 5 + 5 = 15**.

Prim's Algorithm takes edges `{ (a,d), (b,d), (c,d) }`.
Thus, the total weight of this spanning tree is **5 + 1 + 1 = 7**.

Comment: This is a brilliant counter-example. Dijkstra from `d` vertex would still produce a MST.

Comment: This has to be one of the better answers I've seen on Stack Overflow! Explains a complicated issue in a clear manner with simple example.

Comment: nice example. So, can be concluded that in Djikstra, we tend to find a path for spanning tree, which minimizes cost from source to every other destination, where as MST just tends to make total sum of weights as minimum, it doesn't care about making each source to every other node weights minimum

Answer (score 7):

[Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) uses the same underlying principle as Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Excellent. Concise and very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep to a greedy algorithm such as Prim's or Kruskal's. I fear Djikstra's won't do, simply because it minimizes the cost between pairs of nodes, not for the whole tree.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, It's possible to use Dijkstra for minimum spanning tree:

```
dijsktra(s):
dist[s] = 0;
while (some vertices are unmarked) {
    v = unmarked vertex with 
    smallest dist;
    Mark v; // v leaves “table”
    for (each w adj to v) {
        dist[w] = min[ dist[w], dist[v] + c(v,w) ];
    }
}
```

Here is an example of using Dijkstra for spanning tree:

[image: Example of using Dijkstra for spanning tree]

You can find further explanation in Foundations of Algorithms book, chapter 4, section 2.

Hope this help

Comment: This contains pseudo code of the implementation.
please add an explanation.

Comment: Isn't the tree (v1, v5), (v5, v4), (v1, v3), (v3, v2) more minimal than the one shown in the picture?