# Dijkstra algorithm problem

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, greedy

How to apply Dijkstra algorithm for a graph to find the MST in such a way that the resulting tree must have an edge between two given vertices? (ex: MST must include an edge between X and Y)

Thanks

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909281/use-dijkstras-to-find-a-minimum-spanning-tree)

Comment: Dijkstra does not find the MST to start with.

Comment: yes. It needs to be modified in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm is for shortest paths (not MST), but something similar to Dijkstra's algorithm, as modified to find a minimum spanning tree, is called Prim's algorithm. Prim's algorithm keeps a tree that grows until it spans the entire graph. The additional constraint introduced here does not pose much difficulty: you just start with X-Y as your tree.

Specifically, given that your MST must include the edge (X,Y) (if there are multiple such edges pick the one of smallest weight), start with your tree having two nodes X and Y and the edge between them. Now at each step pick the smallest edge (u,v) where u is in your tree and v outside, add node v and the edge (u,v) to your tree, and repeat.

Comment: +1 for Prim's algorithm, very interesting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

Comment: I can simply do this in Prim's but the problem is with using Dijkstra to find MST with the mentioned constraint

Comment: Dijkstra will not find you a MST.  Consider the simple graph with 3 edges, A B costs 4, B C costs 5, and A C costs 7.  Dikjstra will always want to pick A B and A C for a shortest path from A C of 7, but a total tree weight of 12.  But Prim's will always pick A B and B C, since the total tree weight is 9, even though the shortest path from A to C is also 9.  The algorithms are very similar, but I'll never call something that behaves like the later Dijkstra.  If this is a homework assignment, maybe the prof just wants you to realize how easy it is to Dijkstra's into Prim's algorith?